# Logical Error Java - Wrong Computation in BMI

Tags: java, if-statement

The program lets you input the user's height and weight then outputs the BMI and associated health risk. It converts pounds to kilograms.  It also converts the height in feet and inches to meters.

```
    Scanner scanW = new Scanner (System.in);
    Scanner scanH = new Scanner (System.in);
    
    System.out.println("Enter your weight in pounds: ");
    int weight = scanW.nextInt();
    
    System.out.println("Enter your height in feet followed \nBy a space then additional inches");
    String height = scanH.nextLine();

    scanW.close();
    scanH.close();
    
    int heightFt = height.charAt(0);
    int heightInch = height.charAt(2);
    
    int finalHeightFeet = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(heightFt));
    int finalHeightInch = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(heightInch));
    
    double mass = (double) weight / 2.2;
    double finalHeight = (double) (finalHeightFeet * 0.3048) + (finalHeightInch * 0.0254);
    double BMI = (double) mass / (finalHeight * finalHeight);
    System.out.println("Your BMI is " +BMI);
    
    if (BMI < 18.5)
        System.out.println("Your risk category is UnderWeight");
    else if (BMI < 25)
        System.out.println("Your risk category is Normal Weight");
    else if (BMI < 30)
        System.out.println("Your risk category is Normal Overweight");
    else if (BMI >= 30)
        System.out.println("Your risk category is Obese");
```

the correct BMI and risk category output should be:

```
Your BMI is 25.013498117367398
Your risk category is Overweight.
```

but my output would be like this:

```
Your BMI is 0.22261924276759873
Your risk category is UnderWeight
```

I'm very sure there's a problem in my formula but I can't seem to find it. Would be very helpful if someone pointed out which is wrong

Comment: US units: BMI = (weight (lb) ÷ height2 (in)) * 703. Thats a formula.

Comment: Don't initialize two scanners for system.in, one is enough. Closing one  invalidates forever any other scanner from system.in. In your example this isn't harmful, but this may be helpful for future cases

Answer (score 3):

You are not parsing the height input correctly.

Suppose you type

```
5 9
```

as the height.

You assign "5 9" to `height`.

You then parse

```
int heightFt = height.charAt(0);
int heightInch = height.charAt(2);
```

which assigns `53` to `heightFt` and `57` to `heightInch` (those are the numeric values of the characters '5' and '9').

Try this instead:

```
String[] height = scanH.nextLine().split (" ");
int heightFt = Integer.parseInt (height[0]);
int heightInch = Integer.parseInt (height[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are parsing the `chars` which are represented in numerical values.
Take a look on [ASCII TABLE](https://www.asciitable.com/).

For example, if you will put `6 2` as height, the result is actually `54` for 6, `32` for space, and `50` for 2.

Answer (score 0):

```
scanW.close(); // these two are not necessary
scanH.close();
```

```
int heightInch = height.charAt(2); // what if the person is 5' 11" ?
```

I modified your code a bit, take a look.

```
Scanner scanW = new Scanner (System.in);
Scanner scanH = new Scanner (System.in);

System.out.println("Enter your weight in pounds: ");
int weight = scanW.nextInt();

System.out.println("Enter your height in feet followed \nBy a space then additional inches");
String height = scanH.nextLine();

int feets = Integer.parseInt(height.substring(0,1));

// get all the chars after index 2
int inches = Integer.parseInt(height.substring(2));

int totalInches = feets * 12 + inches;
double BMI = weight/Math.pow(totalInches, 2) * 703;
System.out.println("BMI: "+BMI);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println("Enter your weight in pounds: ");
    int weight = scan.nextInt();
    
    System.out.println("Enter your height in feet followed \nBy a space then additional inches");
    int heightFt = scan.nextInt();
    int heightInch = scan.nextInt();
    
    scan.close();
    
    double finalMass = weight / 2.2;
    double finalHeight = (heightFt * 0.3048) + (heightInch * 0.0254);
    double BMI = finalMass / (finalHeight * finalHeight);
    System.out.println("Your BMI is " +BMI);
    
    if (BMI < 18.5)
        System.out.println("Your risk category is UnderWeight");
    else if (BMI < 25 && BMI >= 18.5)
        System.out.println("Your risk category is Normal Weight");
    else if (BMI < 30 && BMI >= 25)
        System.out.println("Your risk category is Overweight");
    else
        System.out.println("Your risk category is Obese");
```